# Problem with my one of next sequence code

Tags: excel, vba

So I have this userform that whenever it would go to the row, it would number itself like 1,2,3 and so on.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
Dim LastRow As Long, nums As Range
Dim number As Range
Dim NextRow As Long
Dim number As Range
Dim LastItem As Range

LastRow = ws.Range("A:A").find("No.", lookat:=xlWhole, LookIn:=xlValues).Row
NextRow = ws.Range("A:A").find(What:="", After:=Cells(LastRow, 1)).Row
Set number= ws.Range("A:A").find("Number")
Set LastItem = ws.Range("A:A").find("Email")


If Not number Is Nothing Then
    'find the occupied range below the header
    Set nums = ws.Range(number.Offset(1, 0), ws.Cells(LastItem.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0))
    'populate max. value plus one
    nums.Cells(nums.Cells.Count).Value = Application.Max(nums) + 1
End If
```

The problem I have is that on my excel sheet, there is a some information in the middle so the ws.Cells(Row.Count.1) would not work since it would input data all the way at the bottom. When I first click on the button on the userform it would input the data on row 5, which is good. But the second time, instead of going to row 6, it would just stay at row 5 and replaced the data. How do I set it up where it can go to the next row. Thank you.

Comment: You need a `+1` in there to utilize the row+1 from what is coutned, aka has data in it.  Also, what is `rank`?

Comment: oh sorry, Rank is the variable number

Comment: where would I put the +1? Sorry I am still new to vba

Comment: `nums.Cells.Count+1` should do you right.

Comment: So I did that, it did go to the next row. But when I hit the button on the userform again, it would just replace the row 6 and I am at the same problem. Before it was "ws.Cells(Rows.Count,1)" and that work fine, it would keep going on to the next row.  But I took away the Rows and replace it with LastItem, and I got this problem.

Comment: so why can't you stick to `ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)...`?

Comment: `LastItem` is a fixed location, so this will always be the case.  Do you want to find the last row in that particular column, then add +1?  That seems more reasonable, unless you intend to iterate `LastItem` by an offset, related to `rank`

Comment: Also, if you're already finding `LastRow`, why aren't you utilizing it?

Comment: maybe you should change `ws.Cells(LastItem.Count, 1).` to `ws.Cells(LastItem, 1).`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in the comments, you are utilizing a fixed location with an offset of 1, which will always be the same final location, e.g., 3 + 1 is 4, no matter the number of times you rerun it.

You can capture the last row and utilize that, depending on if you know which column will have the data (assumption will be "A" (`columns(1)`).

```
Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
Dim LastRow As Long, nums As Range 
Dim number As Range
Dim NextRow As Long
Dim number As Range
Dim LastItem As Range

LastRow = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count,1).End(xlUp).Row 'CHANGED
NextRow = ws.Range("A:A").find(What:="", After:=Cells(LastRow, 1)).Row
Set number= ws.Range("A:A").find("Number")
Set LastItem = ws.Range("A:A").find("Email")


If Not number Is Nothing Then
    'find the occupied range below the header
    Set nums = ws.Range(number.Offset(1, 0), ws.Cells(LastRow,1)) 'CHANGED
    'populate max. value plus one
    ws.Cells(LastRow+1,1).Value = Application.Max(nums) + 1 'CHANGED
End If
```

Made three changes to your code to support finding the actual last row in column "A" and utilizing said lastrow.

Comment: Just came to check back in case other comments were on the main post and noticed that `NextRow` would have been similar to how I changed `LastRow`, meaning that the line of code, and dimensioning, for `NextRow` can probably be deleted